# A circle is given by $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$. Another circle C touches it externally and also touches the X axis. Find the locus of the centre

Tags: conic-sections

Let the centre by $(h,k)$ and radius be $k$

Then $\sqrt {h^2+(k-1)^2}=1+k$
$$h^2=4k$$

I checked the graph of the circle and locus, and got this[image]

If the blue curve is the centre of the new, there has to be some point $(x,y)$ beyond which the condition isn’t satisfied. This is the right answer, but there are two options, with another condition

A)$ \{(x,y): x^2=4y\} \cup \{(x,y): y\le 0\}$

B) $ \{(x,y): x^2=4y\} \cup \{(0,y): y\le 0\}$

Which is the correct option

Comment: Yes, $h^2=4k$ where $(h,k)$ is the centre of the exterior circle is correct. What do you mean by 'but there are two options, with another condition'?

Comment: @s1mple I hope it’s clearer now

Comment: Clearly, any circle of the form $x^2+(y-k)^2=k^2, k<0$ also satisfies the conditions, (B) satisfies. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ne583qwjoh

Comment: does this help you?

Comment: @s1mple yes it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the option A is incorrect, we have to show there exist no circunference such that they are tangent to $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ and to $y=0$ with centre $C(x_C,y_C),y_C \leq 0$.

First of all, we consider this graph:

[image]

This is the same as proving that there exist no point $K$ such that $\overline{JK}=\overline{FK}$, with $x_J\geq x_L$. In particular, by Pythagora's theorem:
$$\overline{FK}=\sqrt{(x_F-x_J)^2+(y_F-y_K)^2}$$
The lenght of the segment $JK$ is:
$$\overline{JK}=-y_K$$
Now we want to show that $$\sqrt{(x_F-x_J)^2+(y_F-y_K)^2}>|y_K|$$
To do this, we square both sides, and we have:
$$(x_F-x_J)^2+(y_F-y_K)^2>y_K^2\leftrightarrow (x_F-x_J)^2+y_F^2-2y_Fy_K>0$$
This is always true because, $y_K<0$ is $x_J\geq x_L$, so the term $2y_Fy_K$ is always positive as the other.

> With this,  we can conclude that th option A is incorrect.

Now, we study this graph:

[image]

In this case, the two points of tangents with $y=0$ and with $x^2+(y1)^2=1$ are the same $B(0,0)$, so every circunference with centre $C(0,y), y<0$ is correct.

> This shows that the correct answer is B.